# PHP - Show the preview of PDF, AI, EPS and SVG files in the frontend

Tags: php, file, pdf, magento

I have a page on my site in Magento where the files inside it are shown.
The images with my php code show them without problems.
The pdf, ai, eps and svg files do not show them and do not allow me to see any preview.

How can I do?
Thanks

P.S. I don't want to use Imagemagick and iframe for this

Comment: not enough detail, no code given, no error given, we need something or we cant help

Comment: you have to display only in desktop ? or mobile also ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Help by voting and accepting answer if its works

Comment: Vector files such as PDF/AI/EPS/SVG have to be rasterized at your desired density into an image before you can preview them in an image viewing tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using HTML object tag :

```html
<object data="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf"  class="pdfview" width="700" height="600" >
    <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href=" ">to the PDF!</a></p>
</object>



<img src="http://localhost/research/coding-challenge/SampleSVGImage_23kbmb.svg" />
```

But for .ai and .eps no option to preview. You can do only thing convert that into .pdf or image format

Comment: Thanks for the reply man. For svg works correctly, But I would like to see the pdf in an image tag to show a preview. Is it not possible to show it as an image?

Comment: PDF cant view as image in <img> tag

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But using the embed tag for pdf files is it possible to display only the contents of the file without the gray background and the bar above that appears? Thanks